# interfaces eth0 nothing en0 list error for mac os

Tags: python, python-netifaces

```
import netifaces as ni
ip = ni.ifaddresses("eth0")[ni.AF_INET]['addr']
```

error

> ip = ni.ifaddresses("eth0")[ni.AF_INET]['addr']
>   ValueError: You must specify a valid interface name.

```
ip = ni.ifaddresses("en0")[ni.AF_INET]['addr']
```

error

> ip = ni.ifaddresses("en0")[ni.AF_INET]['addr']
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Does anyone know why the mac is giving such errors?

Comment: Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error means that there is no interface named `eth0`.  Indeed, this is a common interface name on Linux, but not on MacOS.

The second error means that you are trying to extract a field which doesn't exist.  There is information about `en0` but it is an array, not a dict.  This is like saying `"hello"["addr"]`,  there is no way to access the `"addr"`:th element of a sequence.  You apparently mean something like

```
ip = ni.ifaddresses("en0")[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```

though there is no way out of context to tell whether getting only one address is actually what you want. The array you get represents a number of bindings; perhaps you want all of them?

```
addrs = ni.ifaddresses('en0')
ips = [x['addr'] for x in addrs[ni.AF_INET]]
```

The [`netifaces` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/) actually explains this in quite some detail.